# apoc 3.3.0.1 in neo4j 3.3.1 - Token create operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with FULL restricted to READ

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Having a problem with *apoc 3.3.0.1* on *neo4j 3.3.1* on *ubuntu*. I want to use *apoc.when* cause to create elements under certain conditions.

on:

```
CALL apoc.when(true, "CREATE (a:Test) return a", "", { }) yield value return null
```

i get the following error:

```
Token create operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with FULL restricted to READ.
```

but when calling

```
CALL apoc.create.node(['Test'], { testId: 1234 })
```

everything works fine.

I guess is not a general problem with apoc. It seems to be related to the *when* procedure. 
Also nothing interesting in the debug.log.

In the neo4j.conf I only added `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*`

Answer (score 0):

see documentation:

*apoc.when*

yield value - based on the conditional, executes **read-only** ifQuery or elseQuery with the given parameters

*instead use*

*apoc.do.when*

yield value - based on the conditional, executes **writing** ifQuery or elseQuery with the given parameters